# Postgres Datetime Replace regex

Tags: regex, postgresql, datetime

I've gotten as far as possible alone.

I need to replace the time within a datetime stamp in postgres.

This:

2015-11-20 08:00:00

Needs to be this:

2015-11-20 09:00:00

but for every day of the year (only the time changes)

this is what I have so far. (am i even close?)

```
UPDATE
   events 
SET
   starttime = regexp_replace(starttime,
   E’[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2} [0-0]{1}[8-8]{1}:[0-0]{1,2}:[0-0]{1,2}’,
   E’[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2} [0-0]{1}[9-9]{1}:[0-0]{1,2}:[0-0]{1,2}’,‘g’)            
WHERE
   account_id = 9           
   AND starttime ~ E’[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2} [0-0]{1}[8-8]{1}:[0-0]{1,2}:[0-0]{1,2}’;
```

Comment: why are you using regular expressions? are you trying to change one time to another?

Comment: Also the E'' is unnecessary, you are not using any special characters in your regex so although it is small, it is not needed `select E'[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2} [0-0]{1}[8-8]{1}:[0-0]{1,2}:[0-0]{1,2}' = '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2} [0-0]{1}[8-8]{1}:[0-0]{1,2}:[0-0]{1,2}'` returns true

Comment: can I solve this without using regular expressions (earnestly)? I am trying to change one time to another, but some events are correct, so I only need to change the time on the incorrect events.

Comment: It is possible to use regular expressions but it is a terribly inefficient way to do it. It would be best to stick to using the time functions unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: ok, thank you. why do I get a syntax error when trying to execute this script? `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "{"
LINE 5:    ’[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2} [0-0]{1}[8-8]{1}:[0-0]{1,...`

Comment: Your usage of that strange apostrophe is throwing the error (‘g’ and 'g' are not the same). That looks like something microsoft word might place because they are different at either end.

Comment: Check the available datatypes in PostgreSQL and forget the idea of using a regex for anything else than a piece of text. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am hoping that your `starttime` column is of `timestamp` or `timestamp with time zone` but in the event that I suspect it isn't it may need casting.

```
UPDATE events SET
    starttime = starttime::timestamp + '1 hour'::interval
WHERE account_id = 9 AND extract(hour from starttime::timestamp) = 8;
```

As with Remi's answer, you should refer to the manual for more information on date time functions.

Comment: yes my starttime column is of timestamp without timezone

Comment: then it will not need casting, if that is the case though how does it not throw an error when you use the regex_replace function?

Comment: syntax `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "{"
LINE 5:    ’[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2} [0-0]{1}[8-8]{1}:[0-0]{1,...`
 at the first curly braces

Comment: @RemingtonCharles this error clearly shows you're still using the regexp. Get rid of it!

Comment: I'm using texmate. ok I get the point. thank you. your sql worked!

Answer (score 4):

The documentation is very helpful for this topic.

Typing `add 1 hour timestamp` into the search box at:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/index.html

yields the following page as the first hit:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-datetime.html

So you can do something like

```
timestamp '2001-09-28 01:00' + interval '1 hour'
```

Also if your source is a column (namely mydatecolumn) , this could become:

```
mydatecolumn::timestamp + interval '1 hour'
```

Comment: this would work perfect if I did not have any correct events.. namely events that are correctly set to 08:00:00

Answer (score 4):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but if the *only* thing, you're trying to do is to add one hour to `starttime` timestamp, do not use regexp for date/time manipulations. Just don't.

### Adding one hour

Regexps are for manipulating **text** data, but timestamp is a `TIMESTAMP` - it has it's internal structure which is more complex and allows precise manipulation, while it's text representation is only a "printed out" version of the original data. Again - `TIMESTAMP` is postgresql datatype, so manipulate it directly, not via its "printed out" text form using regexp.

To be more specific, you should do something like this:

```
UPDATE
   events 
SET
   starttime = starttime + interval '1 hour'
WHERE
   account_id = 9
```

But if I didn't get it and you want to change only `08:00` times (as would your ill-formed update statement suggest), you can use `EXTRACT(field FROM source)`:

```
UPDATE
   events 
SET
   starttime = starttime + interval '1 hour'
WHERE
   account_id = 9 AND EXTRACT(hour FROM starttime) = 8
```

(And similary for minutes or seconds, etc.)

### Invalid regexp

Even if using regexps to manipulate `TIMEDATE` is not very wise, your regexp expression is wrong in several ways:

1. you have 2 regexps in `regexp_replace` call, which has form of `regexp_replace(string, regexp, replacement)`. But you used regexp string even for replacement, which does this:

   ```
   select regexp_replace('2015-11-20 08:00:00',
       E'[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2} [0-0]{1}[8-8]{1}:[0-0]{1,2}:[0-0]{1,2}',
       E'[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2} [0-0]{1}[9-9]{1}:[0-0]{1,2}:[0-0]{1,2}', 'g');
                               regexp_replace                             
   -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2} [0-0]{1}[9-9]{1}:[0-0]{1,2}:[0-0]{1,2}
   ```

   So you can see that you just replaced everything with the `replacement` string. Bettew `replacement` string would have references to groups matched by a `regexp`, which brings us to second problem:
2. your regexp expression does not have groups in parenthesis. If I correct that and add references to these groups in `replacement` string, you'll get:

   ```
   select regexp_replace('2015-11-20 08:00:00',
       E'([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{1,2}) ([0-0]{1})([8-8]{1}):([0-0]{1,2}):([0-0]{1,2})',
       E'\\1-\\2-\\3 \\4\\5:\\6:\\7', 'g');
      regexp_replace    
   ---------------------
    2015-11-20 08:00:00
   ```

   which looks almost good. But since you want to *replace* the `08:00`, let's change it to:

   ```
   select regexp_replace('2015-11-20 08:00:00',
       E'([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{1,2}) ([0-0]{1})([8-8]{1}):([0-0]{1,2}):([0-0]{1,2})',
       E'\\1-\\2-\\3 09:00:00', 'g');
      regexp_replace    
   ---------------------
    2015-11-20 09:00:00
   ```
3. this is not exactly a problem, but using `[0-0]{1}` to match a zero (or other single character) is unnecessary, plain `0` would suffice, so I just added the `08:00:00` string exactly. (You can change it to `[01][0-9]:00:00` to match *every* hour, or `[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}` to match any time)

   ```
   select regexp_replace('2015-11-20 08:00:00',
       E'([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{1,2}) 08:00:00',
       E'\\1-\\2-\\3 09:00:00', 'g');
      regexp_replace    
   ---------------------
    2015-11-20 09:00:00
   ```

Comment: Excellent summary explaining the usage of both types and how and why they should be used.